# Play 3 sounds with aud and wait between them

Tags: python, game-engine, audio

I want to play 3 audio files in the Blender Game Engine.

- Play File 1
- Wait 3 seconds
- Play File 2
- Wait 4 seconds
- Play File 3

If I use `time.sleep` the blender game window doesn't update. There is another problem: I can only play one file with `device.play(file1)` and aud. After that the script doesn't continue. I want to start the script when the program is started. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can play multiple files with the same device, what you need are multiple factories and handles. Use a class, put the device as a global variable or as a class attribute and the handle and factory as instance attributes.

To knwo when the file ends check in a low frquency loop (Always sensor with skip > 10) if the status of the handle is false, if it is, it means that the file has ended and that you can play the next one.